# some X of/some of the X of

Tags: meaning

What does "some of the streets of the town" mean?

> 1 **The streets of the town** were made of cheese.

It means ALL THE STREETS

> 2 **The streets of the town I was telling you** about were made of cheese.

It means SOME SPECIFIC STREETS BUT NOT ALL

Now, if one says:

> 3 Some of the streets of the town were made of cheese.

What does it mean?

1. Some streets of ALL THE STREETS
2. Some streets of A FEW MENTIONED STREETS
3. EITHER 1 or 2

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong about the second one.  It doesn't mean "some specific streets but not all"; it would mean "All the streets (in the town that I was telling you about)".  That is the phrase "I was telling you about" is understood to modify "town".

To be clear.  "The streets of the the town I was telling you about" **cannot** mean you told me about some streets.  It means you told me about a town.

> The streets of [Cheddar](https://cheddarvillage.co.uk/) are made of cheese.

Would mean "All the streets". (It's not true, by the way. The streets in Cheddar are paved with stone in the normal way.)

The rest of your question is therefore invalid.

"Some of the streets" just means "Some", that is "not all".

> Some of the  streets of Cheddar are paved with cheese"

Means that a non-zero amount of the streets are paved with cheese and a non-zero amount are not paved with cheese.

Changing "Cheddar" to "the town" changes nothing, except now the specific town is not named but understood.

Changing "Cheddar" to "the town I was telling you about" changes nothing, except now the specific town is not named, but identified by reference.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. I know what 1 and 2 mean. I am interested to know what "Some of the streets of the town" means in 3. Does it mean "Some streets of ALL THE STREETS of the town" or "Some streets of A FEW MENTIONED STREETS of the town.

Comment: I personally think that it can mean either. But I need a confirmation. 1 "I visited some of the streets of the town" There are 1000 streets and I visited some 50 of them. 2 "I visited some of the streets of the town" - There are 1000 streets, but you told me about 50 of them. So, I visited 20 of the 50 about which you told me.

Comment: I think I did understand the question. I think you haven't interpreted "The streets of the town I was telling you"  - It doesn't mean "some of the streets", it means "All the streets".

Comment: Why? How come "The streets of the town I was telling you" means "All the streets"? If I told about 10 streets only?

Comment: I am still not very clear on your stance. Do you agree that "some of the streets of the town" can mean 1 Some streets of all the streets AND/OR 2 some streets of some specific streets of the town (but not all)? I provided an ambiguous sentence "3 Some of the streets of the town were made of cheese."

Comment: It just means "some of the streets" not "all of the streets"    I've edited, Perhaps this is clearer.  Basically your three options are all based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: "The streets of the the town I was telling you about" cannot mean you told me about some streets. It means you told me about a town. //// OK, so how is it possible to specify some streets rather than the town, then?

Comment: "The streets that I told you about in Cheddar"  mean "all the streets that I told you about (but not all the streets in Cheddar)

Comment: Funny, to me "The streets that I told you about in Cheddar" sounds as if the place where you told me about the streets was Cheddar, but not that the streets belonged to Cheddar.

Comment: "B: - You told me that you had visited 10 streets of Cheddar last week. Were all 10 clean?
A: - No, only some of the streets of Cheddar were clean.”
I think it’s clear that “some of the streets of Cheddar” means fewer than those 10 mentioned in the first sentence.

Comment: The reply "No, only some of the streets of Cheddar were clean.” doesn't fit the question.  B was asked about the 10 streets, not about the streets in Cheddar generally.  B should have said "Only some of them were clean"

Comment: I will change it to "No, only some of the streets I visited in Cheddar were clean.”

Comment: Actually, it's strange. You claim that "the streets of X" can't refer to some specific streets, but should refer to all the streets of X. But if we remove "of" then "the streets" can refer to some.  "B: - You told me that you had visited 10 streets of Cheddar last week. Were all 10 clean? A: - No, only some of the streets were.”